# set Response Body of Httpresponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpresponse

I am trying to set the response body of HttpResponse by doing the following:

```
response.Output.Write("Message Body"); //(Ive also tried just response.Write())
```

However when I track my response, the Response Body does not contain this message. Before these steps, however, I am setting the response to Bad Request by doing this:

```
response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```

Which reflects properly. The Response Body is getting set to the default "Bad Request"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Karl's answer, we could also set the flag

```
context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your configuration or code, I believe your issue has to do with an IIS setting called `existingResponse`, which exists in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

There are three potential values for `existingResponse`, they are:

- Auto: Leaves the response untouched only if the SetStatus flag is set.
- Replace: Replaces the existing response even if the SetStatus flag is set.
- PassThrough: Leaves the response untouched if an existing response exists.

I believe `Replace` is what you want, in order to send custom error messages along with the HTTP status code.

Read [Returning a body content with 400 HTTP status code](http://develoq.net/2011/returning-a-body-content-with-400-http-status-code/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to throw a `throw new WebFaultException("Invalid request.", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)`;